# прототипирование, отрисовка интерфейсов

Tags: шаблоны, visio

В данный момент отрисовываю интерфейсы в Visio. В файле куча листов, на каждом листе отрисована форма интерфейса, где встречается одна и та же шапка программы. И если необходимо изменить что-то в шапке, то приходится изменять интерфейсы на каждом листе.
Подскажите ПО, которое позволяло бы собирать интерфейс из примитивов как в Visio. И чтобы была возможность использовать отрисованный элемент интерфейса, к примеру Шапка сайта, и в других интерфейсах. И самое главное, чтобы изменения этого объекта Шапки сайта, учитывалось и в остальных интерфейсах где эта Шапка используется.